# Central area of Images Unclickable

Tags: javascript, image, click, onclick

If one visits http://www.viking.ee/en/windows/tripleglazing/ - where the central play/pause button is unclickable or visits the gallery on the same page, where the images inside the gallery are unclickable there is a general problem with image links not working.

I did not build the theme that the site is based on originally (it was bought from an Indonesian online, no kidding, and configured later on) and could not find out what part of the configuration caused the problem. Could anyone help with taking a look with Firebug or other Inspect Element tools to see what is causing the problem. There is no need to actually propose a solution. It´s just the problem definition I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `ul` tag that causes the problem. After removing it, the button is clickable and works properly. The `ul` tag I'm talking about starts in the 118th line of code and ends in the 125th. It looks like this:

```
<ul class="toimiv">
<li class="prev">
<a  href="#">Next</a>
</li>
<li class="next">
<a href="#">Prev</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ul.toimiv, to be precise. Moving it down 50px makes the flash control clickable

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is a shame that stackoverflow has not yet incorporated sending of anonymous donations or at least making it so that people who get a lot of so called bonus points should get a share of the advertising revenue.

Answer (score 0):

It's the slideshow controls that cause the problem, they are displayed over the play button thus making the clicks not register on the playbutton but on the container of the controls.

You can either position the controls a little higher or lower by changing the `top` css value for the `ul.toimiv` element or you could position the next and previous buttons using relative positioning and the `left` or `right` css properties.